# TailwindCSS not working for <nav> in my Navbar.tsx file

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, next.js13

I have this next13 application in which I want to implement the navbar for my landing page,

TailwindCSS is working absolutely fine for all the other components in my app, but when in Navbar.tsx for the `<nav/>` element, its not working, but for all `<div>`s in this Navbar.tsx it seems to be working fine.

here is my Navbar.tsx

```
import Link from "next/link";
import MaxWidthWrapper from "./MaxWidthWrapper";
import { buttonVariants } from "./ui/button";
import { LoginLink, RegisterLink } from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server";
import { ArrowRight } from "lucide-react";


const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="sticky h-14 inset-x-0 top-0 z-30 w-full border-b border-gray-200 bg-white/75 backdrop-blur-lg transition-all">
      <MaxWidthWrapper>
        <div className="flex h-14 items-center justify-between border-b border-zinc-200">
          <Link href="/" className="flex z-40 font-semibold">
            <span>Logo.</span>
          </Link>

          <div className="hidden items-center space-x-4 sm:flex">
            <>
              <Link
                href="/pricing"
                className={buttonVariants({
                  variant: "ghost",
                  size: "sm",
                })}
              >
                Pricing
              </Link>
              <LoginLink
                className={buttonVariants({
                  variant: "ghost",
                  size: "sm",
                })}
              >
                Sign In
              </LoginLink>
              <RegisterLink
                className={buttonVariants({
                  size: "sm",
                })}
              >
                Get Started <ArrowRight className="ml-2 h-5 w-5"/>
              </RegisterLink>
            </>
          </div>
        </div>
      </MaxWidthWrapper>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

here is my layout.tsx

```
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import Navbar from "src/components/Navbar.jsx"

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className='light'>
      <body
        className={cn(
          'min-h-screen font-sans antialiased grainy',
          inter.className
        )}
      >
        <Navbar/>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

here is my tailwind.config.ts file

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        border: "hsl(var(--border))",
        input: "hsl(var(--input))",
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        background: "hsl(var(--background))",
        foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate"), require("@tailwindcss/typography")],
}
```

globals.css

```
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
     
    @layer base {
      :root {
        --background: 0 0% 100%;
        --foreground: 240 10% 3.9%;
    
        --card: 0 0% 100%;
        --card-foreground: 240 10% 3.9%;
     
        --popover: 0 0% 100%;
        --popover-foreground: 240 10% 3.9%;
     
        --primary: 240 5.9% 10%;
        --primary-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
     
        --secondary: 240 4.8% 95.9%;
        --secondary-foreground: 240 5.9% 10%;
     
        --muted: 240 4.8% 95.9%;
        --muted-foreground: 240 3.8% 46.1%;
     
        --accent: 240 4.8% 95.9%;
        --accent-foreground: 240 5.9% 10%;
     
        --destructive: 0 84.2% 60.2%;
        --destructive-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    
        --border: 240 5.9% 90%;
        --input: 240 5.9% 90%;
        --ring: 240 10% 3.9%;
     
        --radius: 0.5rem;
      }
     
      .dark {
        --background: 240 10% 3.9%;
        --foreground: 0 0% 98%;
     
        --card: 240 10% 3.9%;
        --card-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
     
        --popover: 240 10% 3.9%;
        --popover-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
     
        --primary: 0 0% 98%;
        --primary-foreground: 240 5.9% 10%;
     
        --secondary: 240 3.7% 15.9%;
        --secondary-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
     
        --muted: 240 3.7% 15.9%;
        --muted-foreground: 240 5% 64.9%;
     
        --accent: 240 3.7% 15.9%;
        --accent-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
     
        --destructive: 0 62.8% 30.6%;
        --destructive-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
     
        --border: 240 3.7% 15.9%;
        --input: 240 3.7% 15.9%;
        --ring: 240 4.9% 83.9%;
      }
    }
     
    @layer base {
      * {
        @apply border-border;
      }
      body {
        @apply bg-background text-foreground;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Curious if you change the `<nav` to `<div` does it work?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss no does not seem to make a difference

Comment: LOL at first I read this `kinde-oss` as something more like a chocolate bar inference. (not related to the issue just a humor comment)

Comment: Perhaps update the question regarding details for "the <nav/> element, its not working" to describe and illustrate perhaps an image also with that description? what "fine" would be here

Comment: You might have to pull up the browser and look at the rendered output and trace back to the source - for example in chrome right click the nav and inspect then look at the Computed style then try to trace that to the Style source of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious about what is in `./globals.css`. Make sure that you don't have any CSS classes defined in there that might be overriding your tailwind styles. An example of something overriding things might be:

```css
nav {
  background-color: red;
}

.sticky {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: i have updated the code with globals.css file
there was nothing overwriting the code